# Connect the database to MSSQL

Tags: magento2, database, mssql

I want to connect Magento 2.3.5 to MSSQL database to export records about new orders like (product ID - Quantity sold - price - customer information)
So what are my options?

Before I post this question I found many solutions, but I don't know if it's will work or no?
Microsoft Flow
Blend.co
PDO connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in order to have some sort of integration with a different system (for example an internal site /ERP) I strongly advise you not to work directly with Magento 2 database.

You should use the REST Webservices Magento provides and store the information you need in MSSQL.

In our case we created a C# library just for that purpose, to integrate the Orders / Products / Customer in our internal ERP.

You can find information on all webservices that are available out of the box in Magento here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: No ptoblem if you need any help let me know :)